# cual es la diferencia entre Context context = this; y Context context;

Tags: android-context

Cual es la diferencia entre

```
Context context = this;
```

y

```
Context context;
```

se que **`Context`** es para **`Activity`**, `Application`... etc pero me surge la duda cuando veo **`Context context = this;`** y cuando solo veo **`Context context`**

Answer (score 1):

Este tiene valor asignado del contexto donde te encuentras

```
Context context = this;
```

y este no tiene ningún valor asignado, si lo pones en android studio marca una advertencia de que debe ser inicializado

```
Context context;
```

Answer (score 0):

Como comentas, `Context` es el contexto que puede ser de la `Activity`, Aplicación... etc pero en este caso:

```
Context context = this;
```

Al usar `this` indica que te encuentras en una Activity o intentas obtener el [contexto de un servicio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6446221/get-context-in-a-service) y asignas ese valor a la variable `context` que es de tipo `Context`.

En cuanto a :

Context context;

es solo la definición de la variable `context`, en algún punto debes de inicializar el valor de la variable:

Ejemplo 1:

```
Context context;
...
...
context = getApplicationContext();
```

Ejemplo 2:

```
Context context;
...
...
context = this;
```